# Probability of at least $n/2$ coin flips

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We define p-coin as having a $p$ probability to land on Tails and $1-p$ to land on Heads.

$X$ is a random variables that given $n$-flips results, gives the number of tails ($T$) that we got:
$$X(x_1x_2 \ldots x_n) = \bigl| \{i: x_i = T \} \bigr| ~.$$

What is the probability of event $ A = ( X \geq {n}/{2}) $?  Namely, the probability of the set of $ \{ x_1x_2 \ldots x_n \}$ such that $X(x_1x_2 \ldots x_n) \geq n/2$.

How does one go calculating this? Should I try to calculate the opposing case and reduce it from $1$? Whats the procedure here?

Comment: The probability is $$P(X\geq n/2)=\sum_{k=\frac{n}2}^n \binom{n}{k}\cdot p^k\cdot (1-p)^{n-k} $$ Without any further assumption I don´t see any simplification. Maybe you can apply CLT.

Comment: Thanks, frustrating that we have never even heard the term 'binomial distribution'.
I'll try some algebra to see if this can be sorted out

Comment: If you've never heard of the term binomial distribution, can you say what context you encountered this problem in?  Is this part of a class?  Self-study?  If it's a class, it's odd that you haven't seen binomial distributions; what class is it?  If it's self-study, you should probably go study binomial distributions. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is binomial distribution: $n$ independent trials, with only two outcomes.

We know the probability of head is $1-p$ and that of a tail is $p$.
So $$\Pr(X=k)=C^n_k p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$
Hence the required probability is 
$$\Pr(X=n/2) + \Pr(X =n/2+1)+ \dotsb + \Pr(X=n) \\
=\frac12 \left( 1+C^n_{n/2}p^{n/2}(1-p)^{n/2} 
\right)$$

Comment: I understand everything except the last transition. Where the factor come from? Is this a known formula?
We've been studying probabillity for 3 weeks now and this is the first time I am hearing "binomial distribution" unfortunately.

Comment: The last step is summation of binomial terms. We know that $\sum_0^n C_k^n p^k (1-p)^{n-k}= (p+(1-p))^n=1 $ and $C_k^n=C_{n-k}^n$. Do you get it now?